# appending values to a key with a list as a value

Tags: swift

How would I go about appending to a particular key within a dictionary so that it can contain multiple list values?

desired outcome: key : [ [value, value],  [value, value] ]

This is my attempt:

```
var dict = [String : [String]]()
dict["A"] = ["hey","friend"]
if var arr = dict["A"] {
    arr.append(["hello", "how are you"])
    dict["A"] = arr
} else {
    dict["A"] = ["hey","friend"]
}
```

Comment: What's question or what issue are you having? Please [edit] your question and provide details (don't reply in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new Edit, this is What you would need :

```
var dict = [String : [[String]]]()
dict["A"] = [["hey","friend"]]
if var arr = dict["A"] {
   arr.append(["hello", "how are you"])
   dict["A"] = arr
} else {
   dict["A"] = ["hey","friend"]
}
```

Your value should be array of array of Strings.

So, just change this :

```
var dict = [String : [String]]()
dict["A"] = ["hey","friend"]
```

to this:

```
var dict = [String : [[String]]]()
dict["A"] = [["hey","friend"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = [String: [[String]]]()

dict["A"] = [["hey", "friend"]]

if dict["A"] != nil {
    let appendages = ["hello", "how are you"]
    dict["A"]?.append(appendages)
}

print(dict["A"] ?? "empty")
```

Comment: The output from that is ["A": ["hey, "friend", "hello", "how are you"]] when I'd like for it to be  ["A": [["hey, "friend"], ["hello", "how are you"]]]

Comment: Now I understand; answer updated. You just need to make the value type of your dictionary an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description:

```
   var dict = [String: [[String]]]()
   dict["A", default : [["hey", "firend"]]] += [["hello", "how are you"]]
   print (dict)
```

The result should be like this:

```
  ["A": [["hey", "firend"], ["hello", "how are you"]]]
```